# R: Applying readRDS to a list object of .Rds file names

Tags: r, list, object

I have several .Rds files containing data frame objects and I want to apply a function to each file and bind the data frames into a single data frame. However, when I try to read in multiple .Rds file from a list of file names, I receive the error:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : error reading from connection

Does readRDS not work with lists?

```
########################
# Reproducible example
########################

library(dplyr)

# Create .Rds files
saveRDS(data.frame(a = seq(1:3), b = rep("a",3)),"a.Rds")
saveRDS(data.frame(a = seq(9:11), b = c("j","h","o")),"b.Rds")

# Create list of file names to read
rds <- list("a.Rds","b.Rds")

# Read in .Rds files (error occurs here)
temp <- lapply(rds, readRDS)

# Converts file to single data frame
final <- do.call(dplyr::bind_rows, temp)
```

Comment: I have changed this to "bind"

Comment: Works for me as is, except for the warning on bind_rows for the factor levels.

Comment: I'm on 0.5.0 of dplyr, if that's pertinent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `purrr` package the function `map_df` does what you want. `map_df` returns a single dataframe by row-binding the individual elements.

```
saveRDS(data.frame(a = 1:3, b = rep("a",3)),"a.Rds")
saveRDS(data.frame(a =9:11, b = c("j","h","o")),"b.Rds")

# Create list of file names to read
rds <- c("a.Rds","b.Rds")

library(purrr)
purrr::map_df(rds, readRDS)
```

The edited version corrects a small error in the example.

Comment: This does not produce what I want...the result should be 
data.frame( a = c(1,2,3,9,10,11), b = ("a","a","a","j","h","o")). It is currently data.frame( a = c(1,2,3,1,2,3), b = ("a","a","a","j","h","o"))

Comment: I think the problem is rooted in your example `seq(9:11)` returns 1,2,3. so everything works correctly

Comment: Why do you use `function(rds)readr::read_rds(rds)` here? Works with plain old `map_df(rds, readRDS)`

Comment: I was adapting the answer from a function I wrote to solve a specific problem I had some time ago that involved more than just reading the .rds file. In this context there is no added value. I edited and simplified the answer. Thanks

Comment: This works! Many thanks and it is good to get rid of read_rds() for readRDS.

Comment: I am glad this worked for OP apparently, but doesn't this *read* without *assigning* objects to anything? Perhaps it needs a custom function.