# Parallelize read of 500 independent small .rds files into a singe data.frame

Tags: r, rds

A similar Q might be [R: Applying readRDS to a list object of .Rds file names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42628443/r-applying-readrds-to-a-list-object-of-rds-file-names) , however, that solution is not significantly more efficient than my `for loop`.

In one folder, I have stored `500` `.rds files` named as `file_1.rds`, `file_2.rds`, ..., `file_500.rds`.
Each file contains around `200 records` and `6 variables` which are small chunks of a big `data.frame`.

```
mydf <- data.frame()
for (m in 1 : 500) {
        temp <- readRDS(paste0("H://myfolder//file_",m, ".rds"))
        mydf<- rbind(mydf, temp)
}
```

Do you have any suggestion on a more efficient approach or how to improve the code?
Furthermore, since I created these `500 .rds files`, I am open to improve the `write` process for example by saving in `.csv` or any other format which is far more efficient to read than `.rds`.

Comment: How about using `parallel::mclapply`? And for the write process, you could checkout the `fst` package https://github.com/fstpackage/fst/blob/develop/README.md. Plus, I would read the files into a list and only *once* use `data.table::rbindlist` to combine them into a single table.

Comment: Are you suggesting to use `data.table::rbindlist` within the `parallel::mclapply`? As far as concern the write, each file_x is the result of one iteration of a long and complex function, therefore, my only concern is related to change the extension of file_x in order to improve the following process of read all the chunks previously obtained

Comment: No, I'm suggesting to use `parallel::mclapply` only to read the files (parallelized) and *afterwards* run a single rbindlist on the resulting list.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution using `purrr`.
The problem is that having thousands of `.rds` files to read `parallelized`, I need to use a `loop` to read small chunk in parallel.
Otherwise, I receive a memory error and the progress is lost.

```
mydf<- readRDS("H://folder//mydf.rds")
#Create a vector of string with the names of all rds files to read
rds <- paste0("H://folder//myrds", 1:3870, ".rds")
#Determine the number of iteration to read the files in chunks by 200 each
n <- ceiling(length(rds) / 200)
m <- 1
library(purrr)
while (m <= n) {
#if the loop is **not** in the last iteration
        if(m < n) {
                rds_temp <- paste0("H://folder//myrds", (200*(m-1)+1):(200*m), ".rds")
                temp <- purrr::map_df(rds_temp, readRDS)
                mydf<- rbind(mydf, temp)
#if the loop **is** in the last iteration
        } else if(m == n) {
                rds_temp <- paste0("H://folder//myrds", (200*(m-1)+1):(length(rds)), ".rds")
                temp <- purrr::map_df(rds_temp, readRDS)
                mydf<- rbind(mydf, temp)
        }
        rm(temp)
        gc()
        print(m)
        m <- m + 1
}
saveRDS(mydf, "H://folder//mydf.rds")
```

Comment: How is this parallel? It's not clear from your code. It seems to be sequential.